# "I have experience in developing apps" or "I have experience developing apps"

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct (or sounds more usual)?

> "I have experience in developing apps for Android."

or

> "I have experience developing apps for Android."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one is perfectly ok, and they both sound completely natural and usual.